# Optimal Approach to Api design in Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

The end desired result is a more performant system with less resource utilisation. I want to connect a sql database to cloud functions and host a set pf api's.

Here are two alternatives...

**Alternative one:**
We host each api as a separate cloud function.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloFunc1 = functions.https.onRequest(function (request, response){
 response.send("Hello from Func1!");
});

exports.helloFunc2 = functions.https.onRequest(function (request, response){
 response.send("Hello from Func2!");
});
```

**Alternative two:**
We host a single cloud function with internal routing.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

var app = express();

var helloFunc1 = function (request, response){
 // After some DB OPS
 response.send("Hello from Func1!");
};

var helloFunc2 = function (request, response){
 // After some DB OPS
 response.send("Hello from Func2!");
};


router.get('/helloFunc1',helloFunc1);
router.get('/helloFunc2',helloFunc2);

exports.root = functions.https.onRequest(router);
```

Help me understand the tradeoffs between the approaches and any advantages/disadvantages in either designs.

Also please consider the database connection pooling as a part of the analysis. This wont be a determining factor if we use firebase or datastore, but for native SQL Databases, i'm assuming a lot of connections will impact performance when this is auto scaled.

**EDIT #1**

This is a rudimentary example, but in reality the implications maybe a lot more. Is working with a framework which provides additional functionality like ORM's and shared models, Middleware for AUTH, general convention over configuration approach a real option in a **server-less environment?**
Because we know that these frameworks are designed to run on a always-up server. How will ORM's & frameworks in general deal with being preempted and **how will it affect performance?**

PS. I'm new to Node and Express.

Comment: If you want a discussion to weigh opinions, Stack Overflow is not an appropriate place to post.  Try firebase-talk instead.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/

Comment: @DougStevenson, I have the same dilemma regarding functions usage, but I'm not in the developers group. Can I somehow get into this discussion? Or at least see the results of the discussion?

Comment: @DougStevenson Not everyone has access to developers group. I think this is a very valid query.

Comment: This is a really bad question, sorry, I would recommend looking at the express project (pretty sure IBM hasn't closed it yet) and try to understand what they were thinking. At the end of the day it is just, do I need to use express or not, which is not a great SO question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Deploying Individual Functions

- You get separate tracking of execution counts and easier log filtering in the console.
- The functions scale independently of each other, which can be ideal if you have some endpoints with heavyweight compute/memory needs and others that don't.
- Each function will have its own "cold start" if it has been idle, so if your endpoints have uneven usage distribution you're more likely to run into cold starts.

#### Deploying an Express App

- Everything gets glommed together in the console, you're on your own for tracking individual endpoint usage and being able to filter appropriately in the logs.
- The single function scales all together.
- There is only a single "cold start" to worry about so anyone hitting your API is keeping *all* of the functions "warm" for future executions.

For the time being I'd likely recommend deploying an Express app, primarily to gain the advantage of cold start reduction. However if some of your endpoints have a very different memory/cpu profile it might make sense to separate them into their own Cloud Function (especially once it becomes easier to tweak the cpu/memory profile of functions deployed via Firebase).

Comment: I think, you should although add deployment, debugging and code sharing complexity in this two approaches. In case of express app it would be much easier to debug(I mean locally), and deploy functions, because they will be like a single endpoint, and routing will be inside function. Although, code sharing is much easier, because wee can include modules in default way as it usually done.